# I want to set up a DynDNS service, what do I need to know?

Tags: domain-name-system, dyndns

I'm gathering data from field devices, some of which will soon be behind a cellular-to-Ethernet gateway. Some of the devices need to be polled, and since the cellular carrier will usually assign changing IPs, I'm getting a gateway which has a Dynamic DNS client built in.

I would like to have the devices call my own servers instead of a public DynDNS provider. What do I need to know to get started?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're probably going to use some hardware appliance that only allows you to connect to a few dynamic DNS providers. My DSL router only lists DynDNS, PeanutHull and Comexe and that's all that I've got. It runs Linux underneath but how am I supposed to hack it? Too much effort.

My point is that unless you install a Linux/FreeBSD gateway which you can tweak to your needs, you're probably at the mercy of what your appliance offers.

Given enough flexibility you could even run your own "fake" DynDNS service and point your appliances there, if they offer you the option to define a DNS name that you could use to redirect it to your server. Most of them (all?) don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can start here: [GnuDIP](http://gnudip2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

i have a CradlePoint Cellular Travel Router ctr350 that windows mobile phone connects to via USB.  The dynamic dns does not work because it does not use something like myip.dnsomatic.com or WhatIsMyIP.com to get the public IP address.  Consequently, my dynamic dns address would always be 192.168.0.1 - wasn't tested.

Many dns servers nowadays support dynamic dns updates.  You will want to make sure it uses SSL because most send the password in the clear.  gnudip looks good, but surprised it isn't in the fedora repositories.